# How to record log file in Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions

I know application insight is a good way to log azure functions. However, our data volume is quite large. Application insight is really expensive for us as $3.17/ GB. Performance Counter almost cost half data volume.

Are there any good choices for azure function logging?

Comment: If $3.17/GB is too expensive, how much data are we talking about? There are other logging solutions, but I don't know if they will be (much) cheaper. Also, are you really sure you want to log this much?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to log all the data. However, application insight will record all the data. Can I control application insight only log the error or exception data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is the volume of data being logged, you can configure just how much logging is done via host.json. [Documentation is available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-categories-and-log-levels).

For example, if you only want details about errors being logged, then you would add `logger` configuration to your function's `host.json` like so:

```
{
  "logger": {
    "categoryFilter": {
      "defaultLevel": "Error",
      "categoryLevels": {
        "Host": "Error",
        "Function": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```